# npm WARN .. requires a peer of react@^16.4.0 but none is installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I tried to run a project downloaded from github. However, during npm install the following warnings were shown.`npm WARN axui-datagrid@0.5.0 requires a peer of react@^16.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependecies yourself.`

I ignored this warning and ran the npm start once, but the following error occurred. How can I fix it?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582   throws err;
                                     ^
Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts-ts/package.json'
npm Error! Failed at the axui-datagrid@0.3.20 start: 'react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts-ts
```

Comment: No one is going to click on links to figure out if they're relevant. You should include text of the errors.

Comment: I wrote down the error. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to have [react installed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) as axui-datagrid is dependant upon react:

```
npm install react react-dom
```

The [axui-datagrid example usage application](https://axui-datagrid.jsdev.kr/usage) shows react in use.